# Integration over a Translated Set is Uniformly Continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, uniform-continuity

I'm looking for help with the following problem (working with Lebesgue measure here):

> Let $ψ∈L^\infty(R)$ and let $B \subseteq \mathbb R $ be measurable such that $m(B) < \infty$. If $B+x =\{b+x|b∈B\}$ and if $$F(x) =\int_{B+x}ψ(v)dv$$ then prove that $F$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

I want to argue that if $|x - y| < \delta$ then $|F(x) - F(y)| < \epsilon$. Intuitively, it feels as though $|F(x) - F(y)| < \delta \cdot \| \psi\|_{L^{\infty}}$

The thought is that $F(x)$ and $F(y)$ should only differ on a set of measure $<\delta$. (More accurately, it feels like I should be able to choose a $\delta$ small enough that this is the case). However I haven't been able to show anything like this and I can't seem to work around it to find a proof either.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\! \psi(v)\mathbf{1}_{B+x}(v)\, \mathrm{d}v$ (where $\mathbf{1}_X$ is the characteristic function of $X\subset\Bbb{R}$).

This can be rewritten as $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\! \psi(v)\mathbf{1}_{-B}(x-v)\, \mathrm{d}v=(\psi*\mathbf{1}_{-B})(x)$.

We may assume that $m(B)>0$ (since: if $B$ is a null set then $F=0$ ).
Now your problem has been addressed in this [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570494/convolution-is-uniformly-continuous-and-bounded).

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $\psi$ is a uniform limit of simple functions. When $\psi=\chi_E$ we get $F(x)=\mu ((B+x)\cap E)$ and $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq 2\mu (B)$ when $B$ is an interval (where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure). Now use the basic approximation of Measure Theory which says that you can approximate $B$ by a finite union of intervals. [Ref. Measure Theory by Halmos].

Comment: I'm clear on most of this, but I'm not sure how you're showing $|F(x) - F(y)| \leq 2\mu (B)$?

Comment: If $B=(a,b)$ then $B+x=(a+x, b+x)$ and $B+y=(a+y, b+y)$. $|F(x)-F(y)| \leq \mu  ((a+x, b+x)\Delta (a+y, b+y))\leq 2|x-y|$. @S.H.