# Continuity of Hilbert transform

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, continuity, convolution, cauchy-principal-value

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, be a non-negative, bounded and continuous function, and its support is a compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, we have that $\int f(x) \, dx =1$. The Hilbert transform of $f$ is defined as:
$$
g(y) := H[f](y) = PV \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x)}{x-y} \, dx
$$

What can we say about the continuity and boundedness of the function $g(y)$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

If view the Hilbert transform as the convolution with the function $\frac{1}{\pi x}$, maybe we can use this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531978/about-the-continuity-of-a-convolution-product)?
But $\frac{1}{\pi x}$ is un-bounded at $x = 0$!

Comment: If the Fourier transform of $f$ is absolutely integrable then  $g$ is continuous and bounded. The absolute integrability of $\hat{f}$  holds if for example $f′$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how the absolute integrability of Fourier implies the continuity and boundedness of Hilbert transform, or if you have any reference on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume  $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and the Fourier transform $\widehat{g}$ is absolutely integrable. By the  Fourier inversion formula we get
$$g(x)={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{g}(t)e^{itx}\,dt\qquad (*)$$  The formula $(*)$ states that the function $g(-x)$ is equal to $(2\pi)^{-1}$ times the Fourier transform of the function $\widehat{g}.$ It is a classical theorem that the Fourier transform of an absolutely integrable function
is continuous and vanishes at $\pm \infty$ [see](https://It%20is%20classical%20theorem%20that%20the%20Fourier%20transform%20of%20absolutely%20integrable%20function%20is%20continuous%20and%20vanishes%20at%20%7Bd5e19de0-783b-40f3-9669-e03c4760ccef%7D). Therefore $g$ is continuous.

Consider $f$ as in the question. Then
$$\widehat{Hf}(x)=-i{\rm sgn}(x)\widehat{f}(x)$$ Assume $\widehat{f}$ is absolutely integrable. Then so is $\widehat{Hf}(x)$ as $|\widehat{Hf}(x)|=|\widehat{f}(x)|,\ x\neq 0.$
Hence $Hf$ is continuous and vanishes at $\pm \infty.$

Now we look for additional assumptions sufficient for   absolute integrability of $\widehat{f}$. If the function $f$ is continuously differentiable with compact support, then
$$\widehat{f'}(x)=ix\widehat{f}(x)$$
Therefore $\widehat{f}(x),\ ix \widehat{f}(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$ Hence the function $(1+x^2)|\widehat{f}(x)|^2$ is integrable.
Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\widehat{f}(x)|\,dx \le \left (\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty {1\over 1+x^2}\,dx\right )^{1/2}\left (\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty { (1+x^2)}|\widehat{f}(x)|^2\,dx\right )^{1/2}<\infty$$

Comment: Thanks! I just had small question about the last part. How did you deduce that $\hat{f}(x)$, $ix \hat{f}(x)$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: And, what can we say about the boundedness of $g$?
I'm not sure if continuity and the fact that it vanishes at infinity implies boundedness. Intuitively it should do, but ...

Comment: The functions $f$ and $f'$ have compact support hence they are square integrable. By the Plancherel identity their Fourier transforms are square integrable as well. If a function is continuous and tends to $0$ at $ \pm\infty,$ then it is bounded: there is $M$ such that $|f(x)|<1 $ for $|x|>M.$ By the Weierstrass theorem the function is bounded on $[-M,M].$